# How can I define template specific Ribbons in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, ribbon, microsoft-office-2010

In older versions of Microsoft Word one could define menus and toolbars and store them in templates. They only appeared when the corresponding templates are loaded.
I want the same effect with Ribbons in Office 2010. The Ribbon customization I made so far appears throughout Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you edit the dotm file and add a CustomUI element to it, so that it loads when documents based on the template are opened.
You'll find a step-by-step information on the pages of Greg Maxey [here](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Customize_Ribbon.htm).